# Библиотеки для численных расчетов (метод конечных элементов)

Tags: c, c++

Подскажите, какие можно использовать библиотеки (Си, С++) для расчетов методом конечных элементов (FEM Analysis)? Желательно с триангуляцией. Довольно-таки важна скорость расчетов и возможность трехмерных расчетов.

Comment: В википедии есть обширный список реализаций:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_element_software_packages

Comment: А что посоветуете? Кто-нибудь пользовался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поспрашивал коллегу: из того, что есть в википедии, пользовался тремя пакетами:

- [Deal.II](http://www.dealii.org/)
- [LibMesh](http://libmesh.sourceforge.net/)
- [GetFEM++](http://home.gna.org/getfem/)

По его отзывам лучший - GetFEM++. В добавку - небольшой [обзор](http://sovety.blogspot.com/2008/03/free-software-for-solving-pdes.html) свободных программ для численных расчётов.